# Why isn't the Select Attendees dialog Search taking me to the name I type?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I create a new meeting invite in Outlook, I go to my calendar view and double-click on an empty space and select 'New Appointment'. I then click 'Invite Attendees' and I am presented with the 'Required' and 'Optional' command buttons. When I click either of these, a dialogue appears from which I can choose my person(s), distribution group(s), and/or resources.

If I start typing a name in the Search box at the top, the list of names in the list jumps to where I want to be (e.g. I type Edward, the list jumps me down to people starting Edward).

[image]

This has stopped working, and when I type any name in the search box, the list below remains static.

How do I restore the ability to jump to a name in the list, by typing in the search box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the Search radio button being set to 'All columns', Seemingly, the jumplist functionality doesn't work when 'All columns' is selected.

To remedy this, change the radio button to 'Name only', and the jumplist behaves as expected.

[image]

With 'All columns' selected, you have to click the right-arrow to then show you the filtered list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found an official document about Outlook Address Book search:
[Outlook Address Book search](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/improved-search-experience-in-the-outlook-address-book)

You can use the following troubleshooting:

- Make sure that you have [download the latest offline address book](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2427141):
  [image: oab]
- Next, ensure Outlook is set up to use Cached Exchange Mode:
  File > Account Settings > Account Settings.
  In the E-mail Settings dialog box, select the Microsoft Exchange account that you want, and then click Change.
  In the Microsoft Exchange Settings dialog box, make sure that the Use Cached Exchange Modecheck box is selected.
- If that doesn't help, it is recommended you recreate a new profile and see if it works: go to **Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add**, then re-connect your account.

Comment: My issue wasn't about a missing address book, it was an unintuitive UI experience in the search box. Thank you, though.